# How do I stop "Type '/' from your saved info" (on Edge) from appearing on my site's search field?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, microsoft-edge

I recently added a location search field on my site which shows suggestions based on what you type, but on Microsoft edge, a menu pops up on clicking on the input field. How can I disable this menu from appearing on just this input field of my site?

[image: depiction of problem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="none"
```

The `aria-autocomplete` seems to prevent that box from popping up and the `spellcheck` seems to also stop the spell checker one from displaying.

There are places where autocomplete and spellcheck would come in handy, but NOT in single-line fields like email, website, or an `<input>` where I have my own Bootstrap dropdown-menu/dropdown-item list that displays retrieved DB records via AJAX as the user types (in this case, the Edge popups were ovelaying my DropDown list).

Anyway, adding this code to the `<input class="whatever" id="whatever" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="none" placeholder="whatever" value="whatever" >` seems to solve the issue and you don't have to get all your users to change the browser attributes or mess with the `placeholder`. Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you provided, I think this should be caused by some default settings in Edge. If you want to turn off this prompt, just navigate to: `edge://settings/personalinfo in Edge` and disable this feature like this image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had today the same problem. I had input field without label and empty placeholder. Setting placeholder"..." and making the placeholder transparent makes that edge does not anymore offer "type / ..."
Hth